# How to pass data from separate thread class to activity in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm trying to analyze audio using AudioRecord in a class.  My problem is that I have no idea if the route I'm going to try and thread that into a separate process is correct.  What I want to do is *listen* to that process in the main UI thread and keep updating a text box based on the data in the thread.

This is what I have so far:

```
//RecordActivity.java
[...]
public class RecordActivity extends Activity {
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateResultsInUi();
        }
    };
    RecordThread t = new RecordThread();

private OnClickListener mClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {
    t.start();

  }
}

//RecordThread.java
public class RecorderThread extends Thread {
[...]

@Override
public void run() {
[...audio process code...]
}
```

Is there a way to post back data from my RecordThread class to the RecordActivity class?  Is there a way to connect the handler using 2 different .java files?

Also, is this even the correct way to go about this?  Should I be using AsyncTask instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your `mHandler` as parameter to the constructor of you `RecordThread` class, and use `mHandler.obtainMessage( ... ).sendToTarget()` to pass data to the Activity class

On the `RecordActivity` class, declare and use the Handler as:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
```

Then it dependes on how you called the obtainMessage(), if you used, for example, `obtainMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2)` you can access these by using `msg.what`, `msg.arg1`, and `msg.arg2`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the [Android fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). It gives you a good overview of the key application components within Android. I think this is a must read for anyone starting with Android.

A service might be what you need.

Keep in mind that services run on the main thread, so when executing expensive operations, you may want to checkout [Handling Expensive Operations in the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html).

Comment: While I agree with the recommendation, I don't think it responds to anything in the nature of the question here.  That page doesn't deal with threads, nor message passing, except in the vaguest and most general of terms.